# How one can prove inadequacy of a set of propositional connectives?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My question is that how can I for example prove that connectives and (^), or (v), and implication (=>) cannot be defined using only negation (~) and equivalence (<=>)? What is the general strategy for proving inadequacy of logical connectives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: One strategy is to find some invariant that is preserved by the available connectives but not by some other connective. It works here. Suppose that you build an expression $\varphi$ using $n$ atomic propositions $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ and only the connectives $\neg$ and $\leftrightarrow$

- In how many of the $2^n$ lines in the truth table for $\varphi$ will $\varphi$ be $\mathsf{T}$, and in how many will it be $\mathsf{F}$? It’s not too hard to guess the answer from a few examples; proving it requires induction on the construction of $\varphi$.
- Does $\lor$, $\land$, or $\to$ share this property?